# Which part of the data should I use for Linear Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have a dataset composed of Carbon Monoxide level per 5 seconds (up to 20 seconds) as my independent variables/features and mg/dl (Glucose) as dependent variable. I want to use Regression to make a model for the CO level in breath vs Glucose in blood. Should I use the average of four instances (5s, 10s, 15s, 20s), should I have them all as features? Or should I manipulate it first?

My data goes like this

CO(5s) | CO(10s) | CO(15s) | CO(20s) | mg/dl

161      168       165       170       8.6

Comment: It is best that you plot your variables and dependant variables to see whether there is any seasonality, or how they fluctuate..Yes, usually you have to do some rolling average smooth the trend or some differencing to make your series stationary.  Without knowing details, it would be hard to give good suggestions.